# jade layouts failing to extend

Tags: express, pug

I cannot get jade files to properly extend each other.  Here is my index.jade file:

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
  head
   ... scripts and stuff here...
  body
    include navbar
    div.cont
      div#row-fluid
        a.slice#four(href="#fourbox")
          div.subwindow
            block blog
```

In the same directory I have a file named blog.jade with the follow code in it:

```
extends index

block blog
  .container-fluid(style="height:100%;")
      body(style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden")
        iframe(src="http://website.com", frameborder="0", style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%", height="100%", width="100%")
```

When I run my server in express, the index loads, but fails to populate #four with the correct contents.  Am I doing anything wrong in this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is in the server side cause your jade looks good:

try on the `app.get('/', ...);`

```
res.render('blog', { ... })
```

not

```
res.render('index', { ... })
```

p.s. you have **two body** tag `body(style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden")` care here

And if your index allways include the blog file:

try remove these lines @blog.jade

```
extends index

block blog
```

and change @index.jade

```
block blog ---> include blog
```

Comment: yeah, it was that render issue.  I didn't realize that was the way that extend worked.  Thanks for your help!